# Undefined variable with & without object name in JS

Tags: javascript

When I run the following simple Javascript line...console logs an error.

```
console.log(abc);
```

But when I run the above line like

```
console.log(this.abc); or console.log(window.abc);
```

the console does not throw an error. Instead it prints "undefined".
Why?
Note: 'abc' variable is not defined or declared.

Comment: It's not errornous to refer to a non-existent property, but it *is* erronous to refer to a standalone variable name which doesn't exist

Comment: Where is this being executed? On a browser? NodeJS? Anywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not errornous to refer to a non-existent property, but it *is* erronous to refer to a standalone variable name which doesn't exist.

When one references a non-existent property on an object, `undefined` will be returned - that's how how things work. But standalone variable names, on the other hand, *do* need to be defined before referring to them, in almost all situations. Failing to define a standalone variable before trying to refer to it will throw a `ReferenceError` in all but 2 situations:

(1) When using `typeof`

```js
console.log(typeof foo);
```

(2) When assigning to such a variable in non-strict mode (the variable will be implicitly created on the global object):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // if in sloppy mode, and i hasn't been defined beforehand,
  // it will be created as a global variable
}
console.log(typeof i);
```

If you try to assign to such a variable in strict mode when it hasn't been declared beforehand, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Beautiful answer...Increased my knowledge & makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 0):

When you looking for a variable

```
console.log(abc);
```

Is not defined and should throw

> Uncaught ReferenceError: abc

is not defined in any context at all

however

```
console.log(this.abc) and console.log(window.abc)
```

part of it is defined

```
console.log(this) 
console.log(window)
```

return current objects instance and window objects respectively and have a reference point. the plain console.log(abc) has no reference point

Answer (score 0):

On most browsers and Javascript environments that respect Javascript specification (this may change in other javascript environments where there is no console):

Any property that has not been assigned a value or non existent property (or a function without a return statement) returns `undefined`.

In the first examples, the dot operator is being called. **The behaviour in case you access a non existent property is defined** and it is that to return `undefined`, which is a valid js type. Therefore `undefined` is being logged.

On the last example, on the other hand, the non existent variable throws a ReferenceError. This happens directly, as unlike the first case, no context has been accessed, no dot operator is being called and this is just a plain error.

Comment: What JavaScript implementation produces a value other than `undefined` when accessing a nonexistent property?

Comment: Have we tried on Adobe Script Toolkit? on Unity3D? On some embedded device? There is javascript everywhere. I do not give anything for granted. OP never specified.

Comment: If you don’t know that it might change, don’t say it might change. Vague hedging is extremely unhelpful.

Comment: These conclusions are valid only in browser context or on node console and untested everywhere else.

Comment: The behaviour is part of the JavaScript specification. You’ll be hard-pressed to find a browser or environment that calls itself JS and doesn’t conform in this respect, and implying that you might want to write code to avoid relying on it is bad advice.

Comment: @Ry- My point is for example on Adobe Droplets there is a different runtime behaviour (the droplet blocks, there is no logging, although console.log exists). I agree that is off topic. People will figure that stuff on their own

Answer (score 0):

actually it's not a variable. It is a key which is inside an object. (At this point the object is `this` or `window`). this and window created from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question to ask!. 
To be able to understand this, we must understand [Variable Hoisting in Jaascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

if you want an `undefined` for a variable that is not declared *yet* , well the following would work!

```
console.log(abc)
var abc = 'ss';
```

So, here if we try to access a *declared* variable before it is initialized then `undefined` is actually assigned at the top of function execution. in other words, all the variables are hoisted to the top of their immediate scope level and are assigned `undefined` until they reach the initialization point.

to give you a blunt answer,  trying to use an undeclared variable would give you `Reference Error` while trying to access a declared variable before the initialization would give you`undefined`

and, for objects like `this` and `window`  well they are available objects . so basically at this point people say, `In Javascript everything is present`, meaning, trying to access a property that is not yet there in a js object would give you `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal JavaScript behavior.

> Lets consider a variable `name`

```
var name;
console.log(name);
```

The above wont throw an error, because the variable `name` was declared before using it in `console.log`.

```
console.log(name);
```

This will throw a reference error because you did not declare the variable first.

But,

If name is accessed from an already defined variable( e.g. window, this ), it wont throw an error whether defined or not. Just like the below will simply print undefined, reference error wont be thrown.

```
console.log(window.name);
```

Note that window is already defined by the browser.

Notwithstanding,

```
console.log(window_a.name);
```

the above will throw a reference error because `name` is being accessed on an undefined variable `window_a`.

```
var window_a = {};
console.log(window_a.name);
```

This wont throw reference error because `window_a` is now declared.